# Adding nested objects to mongo array field not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, push

I'm trying to add latitude/longitude points into a mongo array field for an object that has an array of points as a field. This is the code that is creating the nested fields of {lat:, lng:} objects. However, this does not seem to be setting the points attribute of the Kid correctly. The returnedPoints array is in the form

```
[{ lng: '2', lat: '0' },
{ lng: '2', lat: '0' },
{ lng: '2', lat: '0' },
{ lng: '2', lat: '0' },
{ lng: '2', lat: '0' } ]
```

```js
        var returnedPoints = [];
        for (p in pf.particles) {
            returnedPoints.push({"lng" : p[0], "lat": p[1]});

        }

        var newPoints = 
        {   
            "kidID": id,
            "center": {"lng": kid.center.lng, "lat": kid.center.lat},
            "destination": {"lng": dest[0], "lat": dest[1]},
            "points": returnedPoints,
            "gpsPoints" : pf.GPSPoints(),
            "time": clock_time
        };
        kidMaker.pushKid(
            newPoints,
            function(err, kids) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                }
            }
        );
```

The code for inserting the object into the array seems pretty standard and is here:

```js
childMaker.prototype.pushKid = function(kid, callback) {
 Kid.update({ "kidID" : kid.kidID },
  kid,
  { upsert : true },
  function(err, doc) {
   console.log(err);
   if (!err) {
    callback(null, doc);
   }
  }
 );
}
```

How else can I possible set the over 20000 lat/lng points into the Mongo database at once?